Blazor Authentication Issue: Injected Service Has Empty State
I am writing my first Blazor server-side app (.NET 8) and I am struggling with the authentication logic: when injected into a service, the user/auth information is empty.
I have a simple service to hold the user info once logged in:
public class UserService
{
    private string _username = string.Empty;
    public string Username => _username;
    public bool IsAuthenticated => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_username);

    public void SetUser(string username)
    {
        _username = username;
    }

    public void ClearUser()
    {
        _username = "";
    }
}

When it gets injected into a service, Username is always empty:
public class TestService
{
    private string Username { get; set; }

    public TestService(UserService userService)
    {
        Username = userService.Username; <-- Username is empty here.
    }
}

Below is the rest of the related source.
Login (razor) page (Login.cshtml.cs):
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly LoginService _loginService;
        private readonly CustomAuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;

        [BindProperty]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; } = "/";

        public LoginModel(LoginService loginService, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
        {
            _loginService = loginService;
            _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;
        }

        public void OnGet(string? returnUrl = "/")
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl ?? "/";
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = "/")
        {
            if (_loginService.CheckCredentials(Username, Password))
            {
                var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, Username)
                };

                var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

                await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, principal);

                _authenticationStateProvider.NotifyUserAuthentication(Username); <-- Username is set here.

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                
                return Redirect("/");
                
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorMessage = "Invalid username or password";
                return Page();
            }
        }
    }

Custom authentication state provider:
public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly UserService _userService;
    private readonly ClaimsPrincipal _anonymous = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity());

    public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(UserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        if (!_userService.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(_anonymous));
        }

        var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, _userService.Username) };  <-- _userService.Username is set here.
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

        return Task.FromResult(new AuthenticationState(user)); 
    }

    public void NotifyUserAuthentication(string username)
    {
        _userService.SetUser(username); <-- username is set here.
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }

    public void NotifyUserLogout()
    {
        _userService.ClearUser();
        NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(GetAuthenticationStateAsync());
    }
}

Program.cs (a bit trimmed down):
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddDevExpressBlazor(options => {
    options.BootstrapVersion = DevExpress.Blazor.BootstrapVersion.v5;
    options.SizeMode = DevExpress.Blazor.SizeMode.Medium;
});

builder.Services.AddMvc();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<LoginService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<TestService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Login"; // 
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); 
        options.SlidingExpiration = true; 
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });


builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>());

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseSession();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles(); ;
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();

When the user logs in, the username is passed properly to NotifyUserAuthentication in CustomAuthenticationStateProvider (which calls _userService.SetUser) and in GetAuthenticationStateAsync.
It is only in the Constructor of the service that the username is empty.
I am using VS2022 and the app will also run under IIS in production later.
What am I missing?
Update 10/15/2024:
I have uploaded the minimal reproducible example on Google Drive. Feel free to download it to reproduce the issue:
Runnable MRE
Update 10/16/2024: if I use IHttpContextAccessor instead in TestService, it does work (at least in Dev):
public class TestService
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public TestService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        Username = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? "unknown";
    }

    //public TestService(UserService userService)
    //{
    //    Username = userService.Username;
    //}
}

However, when deployed to IIS, it still does not work (the user info via HttpContext is null).
Any ideas of how to get this working when hosted inside IIS?

I finally got this working. Two changes were needed, see below.
First, use IHttpContextAccessor instead of UserService:
    public class TestService
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }

        public TestService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            Username = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.Identity?.Name ?? "unknown";
        }

        //public TestService(UserService userService)
        //{
        //    Username = userService.Username;
        //}
    }

This handled the issue in dev and when run directly in Kestrel.  However, it still did not work in IIS.
To make it work in IIS, enable "Web Sockets" in IIS, see this SO post:
WebSockets must be enabled in IIS
I am not sure that this is the correct way of doing this and I still do not understand why my initial solution does not work: why DI sends blank UserService to TestService.
I have seen various information about using HttpContext in Blazor.  If I understand this page correctly: HTTP Context in ASP.NET Core, it seems that it is mainly a problem with interactive components.  I would prefer a working solution that does not have this potential issue.
Feel free to suggest a better way and I will gladly accept that solution instead!

Possibly your are missing the lifecycles of the objects. I don't see usages of TestService, but  objects are constructed on resolution so there is a chance that the TestService is constructed before the authentication happens, so the constructor is invoked when the UserName is not set. One thing you can try is to proxy it:
public class TestService
{
    private readonly UserService _userService;
    
    private string Username
    {
        get => _userService.Username;
        set => _userService.SetUser(value);
    }

    public TestService(UserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
}

If this does not help it would be great if you could post full [mre] to just copy and run.

I have put a breakpoint in the constructor of TestService and it does not get called until after the authentication (you can see the sequence at the end of my post).  The service is used on a page that has the Authorize attribute. Also, proxying it did not help.  I will try to create a full mre.

I just updated the question with a link to a runnable MRE.  I appreciate your help!

FYI: I just updated my post with a partial solution. Still could use some help, though...

@Zek sorry, has not had a chance to look at the issue yet.
